# Problems with Deconvolution with R (deamer package)

Tags: r, deconvolution

I am having particular difficulty with a deconvolution problem in R.

I have a set of weights in pounds of a product that are contaminated with measurement error.  There are 72 data points.  I also have a measurement standard deviation for scale used to measure the products.  I want to recover an estimate of the true uncontaminated distribution.

I am assuming that the measurement errors are normally distributed and that an additive error model applies.

I am trying to use the following code to deconvolve the data:

```
Weight <- c(1.4760, 1.4740, 1.4700, 1.4760, 1.4720, 1.4760, 1.4760, 1.4760, 1.4746, 1.4746, 1.4710, 1.4710, 1.4730, 1.4730, 1.4710, 1.4710, 1.4705, 1.4705, 1.4756, 1.4756, 1.4770, 1.4770, 1.4752, 1.4752, 1.4735, 1.4735, 1.4743, 1.4743, 1.4747, 1.4747, 1.4736, 1.4736, 1.4732, 1.4732, 1.4731, 1.4731, 1.4752, 1.4752, 1.4760, 1.4760, 1.4746, 1.4746, 1.4709, 1.4709, 1.4754, 1.4754, 1.4705, 1.4705, 1.4707, 1.4707, 1.4708, 1.4708, 1.4753, 1.4753, 1.4692, 1.4692, 1.4754, 1.4754, 1.4700, 1.4700, 1.4752, 1.4752, 1.4764, 1.4764, 1.4748, 1.4748, 1.4749, 1.4749, 1.4745, 1.4745, 1.4671, 1.4671)

plot(density(weight))

# Producing this image of the density

[Original Data Density Plot][1]


# Now Generate the noise vector

stddev <- 0.00000606
mn <- 0

noise <- rnorm(n = 72,mean = mn, sd = stddev)

# and finally perform the deconvolution

ST <- deamerSE(y = Weight, 
               error = noise,
               grid.length = 100)

# Then view the plotted results

plot(density(Weight))
lines(ST)

[Original plus deconvoluted density][2]

 #####
```

I cannot get the deconvolved density to look like the original density even though the standard deviation of measurement is very small.

Any help would be appreciated.